# how to show multiple slideshows on single page

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I set up 2 slideshows on a single HTML page. But they are conflicting with each other.

Changing one slideshow changes the other.
Also, blank slides appear in both slideshows.

It has something to do with the both slideshows using the same global index array.

Can someone please fix my code?

https://codepen.io/kspranav10/pen/jONLJQO

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>v2</title>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ac0201ddad.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b854d36a57.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="slideshow1">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/06/08/21/golden-4387704_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/02/21/19/06/beach-84533_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/15/11/29/sea-418742__180.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://pixabay.com/photos/cloth-fabric-red-orange-yellow-3672088/" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="color_layer"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="text1">LOREM IPSUM</h1>
        <h1 class="text2">LET US SHOW YOU THE WAY</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow_dots">
        <span><i class="fa fa-circle dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-circle dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-circle dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-circle dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div class="slideshow2">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade slide-1">
            <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="subdiv">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <p id="quote">“The biggest thing for me was finding an accredited University. The academic level of education I experienced, online at **** University, was excellent.”</p><br>
                    <p id="quoter">SAIMA SHARI ISMAIL<br>
                     - MASTERS IN EDUCATION</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade slide-2">
            <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="subdiv">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <p id="quote">“The most beneficial part of the program was the ability to network with students across the Middle east. The program also offered the opportunity to work on time management and project management.”</p><br>
                    <p id="quoter">**************<br>
                     - Bachelor of Science in Administration</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade slide-3">
            <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="subdiv">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <p id="quote">“The pursuit of my PHD has been a personal goal since I graduated from University of *** in 2018 . Now that I have begun my journey to Canada Immigration.”</p><br>
                    <p id="quoter">ARUNA DILSHAN JAYARATHNE<br>
                     - PhD</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}



.slideshow1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow1 .color_layer {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slideshow1 .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
.slideshow1 .text1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
.slideshow1 .text2 {
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
}

.slideshow_dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #717171;
}






/* Slideshow */
.slideshow1 .mySlides {
    display: none;
    height: 75vh;
}
.slideshow1 .mySlides img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.slideshow1 .slideshow-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.slideshow1 .prev, .slideshow1 .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.slideshow1 .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.slideshow1 .prev:hover, .slideshow1 .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.slideshow1 .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: #717171;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.slideshow1 .active, .slideshow1 .dot:hover {
    color: #bbb;
}
/* Fading animation */
.slideshow1 .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}








.slideshow2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow2 .img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow2 .subdiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 5% 10px 2%;
    display: table;
    box-shadow: outset -200px 0 110px 0 #000000;
}
.slideshow2 .subdiv .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideshow2 .subdiv .wrapper #quote {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
.slideshow2 .subdiv .wrapper #quoter {
    color: #747474;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*Slideshow*/
.slideshow2 .slideshow-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.slideshow2 .slide-1 {
}
.slideshow2 .slide-1 .img {
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%), url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/15/17/16/pier-569314__180.jpg);
}
.slideshow2 .slide-2 {

}
.slideshow2 .slide-2 .img {
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%), url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__180.jpg);
}
.slideshow2 .slide-3 {

}
.slideshow2 .slide-3 .img {
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%), url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/04/19/36/beach-1236581__180.jpg);
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.slideshow2 .prev, .slideshow2 .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.slideshow2 .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.slideshow2 .prev:hover, .slideshow2.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

JavaScript

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
var slides,dots;

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 8000); // Change image every 8 seconds
}

function plusSlides(position) {
    slideIndex +=position;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    else if(slideIndex<1){slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

function currentSlide(index) {
    if (index> slides.length) {index = 1}
    else if(index<1){index = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[index-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[index-1].className += " active";
}
```